# How to by default not show list of items?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

There is a page where the list of elements is displayed. Also on this page there is a search by value. When I enter a value, the page only displays elements with that value.

I need to make the page show nothing but the search by default. And only after the query, the page shows the elements with the entered value. How to do it?

`home.html`

```
<div class="headtext">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <input type="search" type="text" name="q" prequired placeholder="Put appnumber">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
  {% for application in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>Application: {{ application.appnumber }}, status: {{ application.status }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView, Search

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name="search"),
```

`views.py`

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Application
    template_name = 'home.html'

class Search(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Application.objects.filter(appnumber__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["q"] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check the existence of the `object_list` context variable:

```
<div class="headtext">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <input type="search" type="text" name="q" prequired placeholder="Put appnumber">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% if object_list %}
<div>
  {% for application in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>Application: {{ application.appnumber }}, status: {{ application.status }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Edit: I hadn't noticed that `HomeView` is also a subclass of `ListView`. Change it to:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have an method that will take 'q' from request and return it or None.
Then your get_queryset can use this parameter to return object list you need.

Something like this should work

```
class Search(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_q(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        return q

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.get_q()
        if not q:
            return []
        return Application.objects.filter(appnumber__icontains=q)
```

Comment: Hello. Ther is an error. "views.py", line 32, q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
                     
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: just check the tabs in your editor, I wrote it manually here. Try now if tabs are not correct just check the line 32 and press tab